# Qt: get non-writable location

Tags: qt, testing

I'm writing test for my application where user gives path to some folder and application creates file and write some stuff there. And I want to check correct application behaviour when user inputs some non-writable folder as input.

So I need cross-platform way to get non-writable existing folder using Qt. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QFileInfo::isWriteable](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#isWritable)

`bool QFileInfo::isWritable() const`

> bool QFileInfo::isWritable() const
>   Returns true if the user can write to the file; otherwise returns false.
>
> See also isReadable(), isExecutable(), and permission().

```
QFileInfo dir(folder);

if(dir.isDir() && dir.isWritable()){
    // Folder is writeable
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to find some writable location. But I'm looking for NON-writable location. Just check all standard paths hoping that some folder will be NON-writable?

Comment: Kamil Zaripov: You wrote: `So I need cross-platform way to get non-writable existing folder using Qt. ` My answer does exactly what you asked for. `when user inputs some non-writable folder as input.`  You use `if(!dir.isWriteable())` to know if the folder is non writeable. I downvoted your question until you clarified, since you downvoted my correct answer.

Comment: I know how to check is some path writable or not. I need to write function that will return existing non-writable location for all platforms supported by Qt. `QString getNonWritableLocation() { return ??? }`.

Comment: @ Kamil Zaripov: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to return non-writeable folder, then iterate over the whole harddisk. If you want to find non-writeable standardpathes then iterate over all standardpathes. My answer is still correct, you just need to iterate in this case, you can create a `QList<QString StandardFolderpathes>` and see which folder is non-writeable. There is no function that spits out all non-writeable folders.